# Vue plugin from CDN raises error - Unknown custom element: <grid> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to use `vue-js-grid` using `CDN` but it raises an error.

Can you help me to import it?

https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/vue-js-grid

This is in my `html`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-js-grid@1.0.1/dist/index.js"></script>

<grid ... >...</grid>
```

JS raises:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <grid> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I tried also

```
Vue.use(Grid)
```

JS raises:

```
(index):519 Uncaught ReferenceError: Grid is not defined
    at (index):519
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have an `.umd` export. You can always clone the repo and create it yourself `npm run build --target lib`. The output of `dist` will have a `.umd` file which you can simply include in a page. Read more about [build targets here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html).

Comment: @tao thanks, I installed npm, cd to the package and run `npm run build`, it built something but I can't find the umd file anywhere inside the package. I'm very new to that. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: My bad. It's `npm run build -- --target lib`. or: `vue-cli-service build --target lib`. It's all documented in the link I posted above.